# Remove record from array filter by other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question about array filtering.

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
var names = ["john", "sarah", "dennis"];
var emails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "william.iron@gmail.com", "bruce.lee@example.com"];
```

and now wow can I compare this data and delete it if the name appears in the email??

as a result I should get a third array without **john.doe@gmail.com**:

```
var results = ["william.iron@gmail.com","bruce.lee@example.com"];
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: can you do the check with single email? then use `filter`

Answer (score 2):

You could filter `emails` and check `names` if an email contains the name.

```js
var names = ["john", "sarah", "dennis"],
    emails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "william.iron@gmail.com", "bruce.lee@example.com"],
    result = emails.filter(email => !names.some(name => email.includes(name)));

console.log(result);
```

Another approach by using a regular expression for the check.

```js
var names = ["john", "sarah", "dennis"],
    regexp = new RegExp(names.join('|'), 'i'),
    emails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "william.iron@gmail.com", "bruce.lee@example.com"],
    result = emails.filter(email => !regexp.test(email));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `filter`:

```js
var names = ["john", "sarah", "dennis"];
var emails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "william.iron@gmail.com", "bruce.lee@example.com"];

var result = emails.filter(email => !names.find(name => email.includes(name)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter()` and `Array.find()` in combination:

```js
var names = ["john", "sarah", "dennis"];
var emails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "william.iron@gmail.com", "bruce.lee@example.com"];
var res = emails.filter(email => !names.find(name => email.includes(name)));
console.log(res);
```

If you are also concern with IE browsers then use simple function declarations and do not use `includes()` use `indexOf()` instead:

```js
var names = ["john", "sarah", "dennis"];
var emails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "william.iron@gmail.com", "bruce.lee@example.com"];
var res = emails.filter(function(email) {
  return !names.find(function(name) {
     return (email.indexOf(name) !== -1);
  });
})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array.prototype.filter`, `array.prototype.some` and `string.prototype.includes`:

```js
var names = ["john", "sarah", "dennis"];
var emails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "william.iron@gmail.com", "bruce.lee@example.com"];
var res = emails.filter(email => !names.some(name => email.includes(name)));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var names = ["john", "sarah", "dennis"];
var emails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "william.iron@gmail.com", "bruce.lee@example.com"];

const result = emails.filter(email => { 
  let nameInMail = true
  
  names.forEach(name => {
    if (!nameInMail) {
      return
    }

    nameInMail = !(email.indexOf(name) >= 0)  
  })
  
  return nameInMail
})

console.log(result)
```

EDIT: others answer are better than mine haha
Use `.some()` look like the best way